# How to hide/show all react component when loading screen is showing up?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

For my case, loading screen will show up if the page is changed. 
for example:
http://localhost:3000/    ----> http://localhost:3000/fr

loading screen will show up for page transition

I want to hide other component. How can I do that?

```
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
import "../styles/main.css";
import Router from "next/router";
import { useState } from "react";
import Loader from "../components/Loader/Loader";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);
  Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", (url) => {
    // inspect the router changing start
    console.log("Router change...");
    setloading(true);
  });

  Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", (url) => {
    // inspect the router changing complete
    console.log("Router change completed");
    setloading(false);
  });

  return (
    <>

      <Loader loadingbool={loading}/>
      <Component {...pageProps}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some conditions in your JSX with a ternary that depends on the value of `loading`

```
  return (
      <>
        {loading ? <Loader loadingbool={loading}/> : <Component {...pageProps}/>}
      </>
    );
```

---

If you want the components to still be rendered, conditionally add a class dependant on the value of `loading` (and use `.hidden` to hide with css.)

```
  return (
    <>
      <Loader loadingbool={loading} {...(!loading && {className:'hidden'})} />
      <Component {...pageProps} {...(loading && {className:'hidden'})} />
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the fade out animation of the loading Screen  is not working. Also, i don't think it is pre-rendering. If not pre-rendering , my loading screen is useless

Comment: Which fade out animation are you referring to? What do you mean by pre-rendering?

Comment: I mean,I just want to hide it but not destroy it.
 the dom is still here but set it invisible. 
Loading screen ease  in out. It's height become 0 slowly
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0; 
  }

Answer (score -1):

By using the boolen expression we can hide the screen data

```js
 return (
      <>
        {loading ? <Loader loadingbool={loading}/> : <Component {...data}/>}
      </>
    );
```